# Calculate an elliptical arc start and end angles given two vectors

Tags: c++, qt, math, ellipse, cgm

I am working on a program which draws shapes based on a cgm file input. I am trying to draw  elliptical arc and it gives the opening portion in terms of a start and end vector from the center of the arc. I need help calculating the angle to the vector so I can draw.

I have been trying to use the standard atan2(y/x) but then I found it is valid for circles and not ellipses.

This image gives an example of what I'm trying to do. I am looking for angles A and B.

edit: This is related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117032/drawing-elliptical-arc-with-qpainter-creates-wrong-angle). (Also note, this question is based on the math behind my problem while the other question was for programming help with qt.)

The wiki page on [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_form_in_canonical_position) kind of shows why the math isn't working but I'm not sure how to implement it.

[image: Elliptical Angle Example]

Comment: What are the expected values of A and B? Is the size of the ellipse given?

Comment: @kennytm I'm not sure what the exact values are. Yes the size of the ellipse is given. I update the original question with a link to my other question on which this is built on.

Answer (score 0):

The angles A and B you were drawing in your picture in fact have nothing to do with the ellipse.

Just calculate once the angle between the x-axis and the line from origin to point (75,50). This is given by [`arctan(50/75) = 33.69°`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan(50%2F75)). And by symmetry, it is the same as the angle to point (75, -50).

Then, by simple trigonometry, for angle `A` you get `A = 360° - 33.69°`, whereas for `B` you get `B= 180° + 33.69°`.

Considering `A`, this is the same information that is obtained by `atan2(-50, 75)`. However, the result of `atan2` is in (i) in radians and (ii) in the range `[-pi, pi]`. You could add `2*pi` and express it in angles and you get the same result as above.

Comment: That is what I tried originally but I'm using the results to draw the angle in qt using the drawArc function [qpainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) class. If I use those answers the arc is not drawn correctly.